# I cannot access same route on multiple route groups in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am new to laravel and I have some route groups and middlewares. My problem is that when I use same route on different route groups, it only picks the routes in the bottom route group.

Below are my codes

AdminMiddleware:

```
 if(Sentinel::check() && Sentinel::getUser()->roles()->first()->slug == 'admin')
    return $next($request);
 else
    return redirect()->back();
```

TeacherMiddleware:

```
if(Sentinel::check() && Sentinel::getUser()->roles()->first()->slug == 'teacher')
   return $next($request);
else
   return redirect()->back();
```

wep.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['teachers']], function () {
   Route::get('/adminportal', ['as' => 'getAdminPortal', 'uses' => 'AdminPortalController@getAdminPortal']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
   Route::get('/adminportal', ['as' => 'getAdminPortal', 'uses' => 'AdminPortalController@getAdminPortal']);
   Route::get('/admin/dashboard', ['as' => 'getDashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@Dashboard']);
});
```

So at the above code, what I actually want to achieve is that, when a user has a role of **admin**, he should be able to access both `/adminportal and /admin/dashboard` but in this case, user with the role **admin** can only access `/admin/dashboard`but cannot access the `/adminportal` route.

**Please how do I solve this please?**

Comment: Sidenote; If you're using `Sentinel`, maybe look into using `->inRole($slug)`; if you get into multiple roles per user you won't be able to rely on the `->first()` method.

Comment: @TimLewis, so how do I write the middleware please by using `->inRole($slug)`? I tried this `Sentinel::getUser()->roles()->inRole($slug)` but it throws error

Comment: I did this `Sentinel::getUser()->inRole($slug)` but the problem remain same

Comment: `if(\Sentinel::getUser()->inRole($slug);` is the correct syntax, where `$slug` is something like `"admin"`, etc. Technically, you're defining `/adminportal` twice, once in the `teachers` middleware group, and once in the `admin` middleware group. You're likely getting the logic from the `teachers` one, and failing that validation check. Should it be `/teacherportal` instead?